# How to import javax.annotation.Nullable?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I use Android Studio 3.x and Gradle build script.

How can I import javax.annotation.* packages?

Here is my Gradle depedencies example.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
```

Comment: What ever this is, works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following if You olny need annotation feature

> implementation "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"

But need to very careful while using this, Reason being these classes are provided by multiple libraries like

> implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
>
> implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
>
> implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$versions.kotlin'

If You are using them already either You don't include that one or use `exclude` with them to avoid any build errors.

```
implementation (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$versions.kotlin){
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
        exclude module: 'jsr250'
}
```